# How to format piped output in powershell to a line

Tags: powershell, format, key-value

I have a script powershell to get PercentProcessorTime of processes.

```
$Processes = (get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process) 
$Processes | %{  New-Object psobject -Property `
     @{ Time = $_.PercentProcessorTime; 
        Name = ($_.name -replace "#\d+", "" )}}`
 | ?{ $_.Name -notmatch "_Total|Idle" } `
 | Group-Object Name `
 | %{ New-Object psobject -Property `
      @{ Name = $_.Name; 
         Sum = ($_.Group | Measure-Object Time -Sum ).Sum }} `
 | Format-Table
```

Format of result as below:
[image: Format of result]

But I want to format result as below to insert to database:

```
OK |Idle=100 System=6 smss=0 csrss=0 wininit=0 services=0 lsass=0 lsm=0 svchost=18 ICTrigger=0 nvvsvc=0 ICDCMGR64=0 svchost#2=0 winlogon=0 svchost#3=0 svchost#4=0 svchost#5=0 igfxCUIService=0 svchost#6=0 spoolsv=0 svchost#7=0 armsvc=0 ShieldStart=0 svchost#8=0 GateMan=0 HeciServer=0 Jhi_service=0 NHCAAgent=0 nvxdsync=0 nvvsvc#1=0 nscp=0 PaSvc=0 pcdrmsvc=0 NSCHIM=0 ASDSvc=0 secugate64=0 WindowsSecuService=0 WinFil32=0 WmiPrvSE=0 svchost#9=0 papersrv64=0 WUDFHost=0 svchost#10=0 svchost#11=0 WmiP rvSE#1=0 PaTray=0 unsecapp=0 WmiPrvSE#2=0 LMS=0 SWMAgent=0
```

Please help me to solve it.
Thanks very much ^^

Comment: `Format-*` cmdlets are for _display formatting_, not for producing data. Please include your desired output directly in your question, preferably as text, along with an explanation. Also, please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is a classic example to use convertto-stringdata which default doesnot come with PS. Convertfrom-stringdata breaks the data in Hashtable format and the reverse will make it as key=value pair. [This Link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/17/simplify-powershell-hash-table-creation-with-a-simple-cmdlet/) will help you to use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an "easy", builtin command for it, but it doesn't take much to update the function to do what you want:

```
$Processes = (get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process) 

$procStrings = @()
$Processes | %{  New-Object psobject -Property `
     @{ Time = $_.PercentProcessorTime; 
        Name = ($_.name -replace "#\d+", "" )}}`
 | ?{ $_.Name -notmatch "_Total|Idle" } `
 | Group-Object Name `
 | %{ 
    $procStrings += "$($_.Name)=$(($_.Group | Measure-Object Time -Sum ).Sum)"}

$procStrings -join " "
```

Basically, I added an array to hold the string key/value paris and replaced the final New-Object with code to create the desired string. Finally it is joined with spaces to create the final string.

You could absolutely skip the array part and just build up the string directly, instead of creating an array, I just like that approach :)

It doesn't include the "OK |" in the beginning, i don't know what you constitutes an OK, but I'm sure you can add yourself to get what you want :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did it ^^